# Having trouble with authentication when doing rest api to retrieve Bigquery job information

Tags: google-bigquery, google-authentication

I am trying to do http request to get information for a job that was submitted by another script.  This script has the job id and the project. I read on Oauth20 and saw that using Application Default Credentials is the recommended way. 
I have exported the default auth:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS= /test/proj-service-key-file.json
```

Here is my code:

```
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
from google.cloud import bigquery
import requests
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession 
import google.auth

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
session = google.auth.transport.requests.AuthorizedSession(credentials)
job_url="https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/" + self.project + "/jobs/" + job_id + "?maxResults=1"
    job_query_results = session.request('GET',job_url)
```

I am getting the following error:
    self.credentials.before_request(
    AttributeError: '_JWTAccessCredentials' object has no attribute 'before_request'

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.  I had to set up the scopes explicity and that did the trick:

```
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control',
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery']
    credentials = credentials.create_scoped(scopes)
    http = httplib2.Http()
    if credentials.access_token_expired:
        credentials.refresh(http)
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    response, content = http.request(job_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the space in your export statement:

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/test/proj-service-key-file.json`

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That space was added inadvertantly when I tried to chg the name of the key file when posting my question. I don't really have that space in the export stmt that I actually ran.   Any other suggestions?